# Python and HTML Producing Tables

Tags: python, html, html-table

I'm having trouble with trying to produce two columns using python and html. So I just want it to only have two columns with any amount of rows. Here is a visual of what I'm trying to produce:

[image]

This is my python code:

```
file_name = 'test.html'

test_file = open('test.html', 'w')

test_file.write('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Dogs </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="5">
''')

dog_names = ['Bob', 'Kenny', 'Robin', 'Ben', 'Tom', 'Steve']

dog_amount = len(dog_names)
index = 0

while dog_amount > index:
    name = dog_names[index]
    test_file.write('''           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>''' + name + '''</p>
                </td>
            </tr>\n''')
    index += 1

test_file.write('''        </table>
    </body>
</html> ''')
```

and this is what is produced in the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Dogs </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="5">
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Bob</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Kenny</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Robin</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Ben</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Tom</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>Steve</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
while dog_amount > index:
    test_file.write('''           <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>''' + dog_names[index]+ '''</p>
                </td><td align="center" valign="center">
                    <p>''' + dog_names[index+1]+ '''</p>
                </td>

            </tr>\n''')
    index += 2
```